# <link rel="stylesheet" > afetar apenas uma seção do html

Tags: html, css

Há alguma forma de fazer um  afectar apenas uma secção do html? Por exemplo eu quero por um link externo que só vai afectar uma das divs com um id especifico, como faço isso?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas basta você deixar dentro do ´<link rel="stylesheet" >´ que vc vai indexar apenas as classes do ID que vc quer atingir.` #seuID { suas classes css }`

Comment: eu precisei usar um bootstrap para criar um slideshow de imagens, mas depois de colocar o bootstrap varias coisas no website ficaram desorganizadas, gostava que o bootstrap apenas tivesse efeito na div id="galeira"

Comment: Isso aconteceu provavelmente por que vc está usando classes que tem o mesmo nome que as classes nativas do Bootstrap.

Comment: sim, eu já tinha entendido isso, há alguma maneira de por o bootstrap funcionar apenas numa div?

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer um Scope de CSS e provavelmente convertes os .Less do Bootstrap em CSS e desvincular os estilos do HTML/Body. Se vc entende de pre-processado de CSS aqui vc vai encontrar a resposta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065/limit-the-scope-of-bootstrap-styles